# Почему скрипт не запускается из крона?

Tags: cron, bash, linux

Сам скрипт

```
#!/bin/bashecho "archive is started"tar -cvJf archive.tar.xz /home/user/archivepython archive.py archive.tar.xzrm -fr archive.tar.xzecho "archive is finished"
```

Вызов из крона

```
/home/user/achive/archive.sh > /home/user/archive/at[`date +%H:%M`]
```

В итоге в папке нет файлов, хотя если запускать вручную, то все ок.

Comment: 1. что говорит /var/log/cron ? 2. скрипт запускается с правами рута? Если нет - он может писать в текущую папку?

Comment: Посмотрел, что пишет. Пишет такое:>`/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`\`'`>`/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Скрипт может писать в папку, поставил для проверки права 777.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался методом проб и ошибок. Дело в % вот здесь: `date +%H:%M` Их надо прописать через слэш (правда, не знаю почему).

```
/home/user/achive/archive.sh > /home/user/archive/at[`date +\%H:\%M`]
```

и в папке появляются файлы.